# Websphere 8.5 Always hung thread at same time

Tags: websphere, jdk1.7

We're using WebSphere AppServer 8.5 for Web processing, but at a specific point in time, such as 8 a.m., we get thread deadlocks and eventually the thread hangs. One hour later, the AppServer is running slowly. One hour later, however, the AppServer recovers. After checking the scheduled tasks of the operating system, it is found that no task is executed at 8:00 a.m.

```
1CIJAVAVERSION JRE 1.7.0 Windows 7 x86-32 build  (pwi3270sr9-20150417_01(SR9) )
1CIVMVERSION   VM build R26_Java726_SR9_20150406_1443_B242981
1CIJITVERSION  tr.r11_20150401_88894
1CIGCVERSION   GC - R26_Java726_SR9_20150406_1443_B242981
1CIJITMODES    JIT enabled, AOT enabled, FSD disabled, HCR disabled
1CIRUNNINGAS   Running as a standalone JVM
1CIPROCESSID   Process ID: 10332 (0x285C)
1CICMDLINE     C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\bin\java.exe -DrptNextgenDebug -Drptserver.rootDiscoveryUrl=http://9.84.122.22:7081/deployment/ -Drptagent.agentName=localhost -Drptagent.engineName=localhost -Drptagent.scheduleName=sched2 -Drptagent.rptDeployDir=file:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/IBM/RPTCitrixTest871/deployment_root/gdaronde/A1E515CFE7BA0690C143E56139636135/ -Drptagent.secure=false -Drptagent.securePort=7444 -Drptagent.installBase=C:/IBMRPT_871/SDP/Majordomo/ -Xmx1200m -DrptLocale=fr_FR -Drptserver.domoHeavyClass=com.ibm.rational.test.lt.kernel.runner.impl.RPTNextgenRunner -Drptserver.domoLiteUrl=file:/C:/IBMRPT_871/SDP/Majordomo/lib/ -Drptserver.domoLiteClass=com.ibm.rational.test.lt.nextgen.Domo -cp C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\Majordomo\lib\boot.jar com.ibm.rational.test.lt.boot.DomoBooter
1CIJAVAHOMEDIR Java Home Dir:   C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre
1CIJAVADLLDIR  Java DLL Dir:    C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\bin
1CISYSCP       Sys Classpath:   C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\default\jclSC170\vm.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\se-service.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\math.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\jlm.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmorb.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmorbapi.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmcfw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmpkcs.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmcertpathfw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmjgssfw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmjssefw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmsaslfw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmjcefw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmjgssprovider.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmjsseprovider2.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmcertpathprovider.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\xmldsigfw.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\xml.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\ibmgpu.jar;
1CIUSERARGS    UserArgs:
2CIUSERARG               -Xoptionsfile=C:\IBMRPT_871\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\default\options.default
```

```
0MEMUSER
1MEMUSER       JRE: 1,320,399,028 bytes / 2770 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--VM: 1,315,550,900 bytes / 2282 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Classes: 16,393,128 bytes / 508 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Memory Manager (GC): 1,284,062,768 bytes / 446 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Heap: 1,258,291,200 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 25,771,568 bytes / 445 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Threads: 13,546,748 bytes / 236 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Stack: 475,728 bytes / 50 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Native Stack: 12,746,752 bytes / 50 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 324,268 bytes / 136 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Trace: 444,968 bytes / 353 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JVMTI: 17,328 bytes / 13 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JNI: 70,504 bytes / 290 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Port Library: 9,632 bytes / 74 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 1,005,824 bytes / 362 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--JIT: 3,880,280 bytes / 225 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 1,048,576 bytes / 2 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 524,336 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 2,307,368 bytes / 222 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--Class Libraries: 967,848 bytes / 263 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Harmony Class Libraries: 1,024 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--VM Class Libraries: 966,824 bytes / 262 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--sun.misc.Unsafe: 72,360 bytes / 10 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Direct Byte Buffers: 66,040 bytes / 8 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Other: 6,320 bytes / 2 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 894,464 bytes / 252 allocations
```

```
3XMTHREADINFO      "Brother-7" J9VMThread:0x518FDD00, j9thread_t:0x527F7634, java/lang/Thread:0x030B1D80, state:P, prio=5
3XMJAVALTHREAD            (java/lang/Thread getId:0x32, isDaemon:true)
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0xA44, native priority:0x5, native policy:UNKNOWN, vmstate:P, vm thread flags:0x01020000)
3XMCPUTIME               CPU usage total: 0.0 secs, user: 0.0 secs, system: 0.0 secs
3XMTHREADBLOCK     Parked on: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x02E83C68 Owned by: <unknown>
3XMHEAPALLOC             Heap bytes allocated since last GC cycle=0 (0x0)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Java callstack:
4XESTACKTRACE                at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(Native Method)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:198)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2055)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:501)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:690)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15 (0x77A0F8CD [ntdll+0x1f8cd])
4XENATIVESTACK               WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43 (0x75491194 [kernel32+0x11194])
4XENATIVESTACK               WaitForSingleObject+0x12 (0x75491148 [kernel32+0x11148])
4XENATIVESTACK               j9thread_park+0xba (j9thread.c:2631, 0x73B71C8A [J9THR26+0x1c8a])
4XENATIVESTACK               jclCallThreadPark+0x198 (threadpark.c:82, 0x666C2F88 [jclse7b_26+0x42f88])
4XENATIVESTACK               sun_misc_Unsafe_park+0x5a (smunsafe.asm:14351, 0x666B760A [jclse7b_26+0x3760a])
4XENATIVESTACK               javaProtectedThreadProc+0x9d (vmthread.c:1881, 0x66831DBD [j9vm26+0x51dbd])
4XENATIVESTACK               j9sig_protect+0x44 (j9signal.c:150, 0x6BB9F8B4 [J9PRT26+0xf8b4])
4XENATIVESTACK               javaThreadProc+0x39 (vmthread.c:298, 0x66832739 [j9vm26+0x52739])
4XENATIVESTACK               thread_wrapper+0xda (j9thread.c:1154, 0x73B747AA [J9THR26+0x47aa])
4XENATIVESTACK               _endthread+0x48 (0x67E3C55C [msvcr100+0x5c55c])
4XENATIVESTACK               _endthread+0xe8 (0x67E3C5FC [msvcr100+0x5c5fc])
4XENATIVESTACK               BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 (0x7549337A [kernel32+0x1337a])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63 (0x77A292B2 [ntdll+0x392b2])
4XENATIVESTACK               RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36 (0x77A29285 [ntdll+0x39285])
```

We analyzed the thread information and found that there may be a GC conflict between WebSphere AppServer 8.5 and JDK 1.7, which will be resolved after the server is restarted.

Comment: JDK is more than 7 years old

Comment: Yes, JDK 1.7 is too old to use. So we upgraded it to JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

We found the same problem. We used Websphere 8.2, at a specific point in time, the Websphere was hung all threads and made a deadlock in JVM. So, we create a case on IBM Support and they said that the Java 1.7 Full GC and main thread of WebSphere conflict at some point in time. 
We already upgraded to WebSphere 9.0.5 and JDK 1.8. The problem has been resolved.

IBM Docs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/1.1.0.15?topic=threads-blocked-thread-information

Comment: Thanks john, I upgraded to WebSphere 9.0, It works.

Comment: But john, another question, Why does this problem occur in Webspere 8 with JDK 1.7?

Comment: I don't know why, but just upgrade Websphere to v9.0 and JDK 1.8. it will be fine

Comment: To Huiyg, NO ANY DETAIL. Our situation is very similar. IBM helpdesk said it may be a bug that they have fixed in versions later than Websphere 9.0, so he suggested that we upgrade the WebSphere or use the Tomcat, and MUST upgrade the JDK to 1.8 or higher.